# How to check if Group on sub site exists CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom

I want to copy a SharePoint Permissions Groups to subsites that does not have that group already. The permissions inheritance is broken.

Lets say we have the following site structure:

```
https://x.sharepoint.com/SubsiteLevel1/
https://x.sharepoint.com/SubsiteLevel1/SubsiteLevel2/
```

How would I go about getting the site specific Groups that are used on SubsiteLevel2 (or any site). The problem I am facing is that when I get the Groups from a site I can only get the SiteGroups. So all groups on the Site Collection.

```
GroupCollection groupCollection = web.SiteGroups;
```

How can I get the specific groups that are used on a sub site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it via the `RoleAssignmentCollection.Groups` property.

Check the below code:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("site-collection-url"))
{   
    //pass the sp web 
    Web oWeb = context.Site.OpenWeb("SubsiteLevel1");
    context.Load(oWeb);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var groups = oWeb.RoleAssignments.Groups;
    context.Load(groups);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group group in groups)
    {                    
        Console.WriteLine(group.Title);
    }   

}
```

To get the 2nd level subsite groups, replace the

```
context.Site.OpenWeb("SubsiteLevel1");
```

to below (use the server-relative url of the sp web):

```
context.Site.OpenWeb("SubsiteLevel1/SubsiteLevel2");
```

MSDN - [RoleAssignmentCollection.Groups property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roleassignmentcollection.groups.aspx)